# Getting this error "Trying to get property of non-object" for a function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, object, plugins

This is a function to removed some banners, I know the error is happening around the if ( ! in_array( $current_screen->post_type, $post_types ) ) but I don't know to properly fix it.

```
function lsx_tec_disable_lsx_banner( $disabled ) {
    global $current_screen;
    $post_types = apply_filters( 'tribe_is_post_type_screen_post_types', Tribe__Main::get_post_types() );
    if ( ! in_array( $current_screen->post_type, $post_types ) ) {
        $disabled = true;
    }
    if ( is_null( $id ) && false !== strpos( $current_screen->id, 'tribe' ) ) 
    {
        $disabled = true;
    }
    if ( is_single() && tribe_is_event() ) {
        $disabled = true;
    }
    return $disabled;
}
```

Comment: There is problem with this line "if ( ! in_array( $current_screen->post_type, $post_types ) ) {"

Comment: What is the problem? I tried a few thing but got errors

Comment: can you try to print the both $current_screen->post_type and $post_types ? You can see the problem. You have tried to get data from non-object.

Comment: `$current_screen` probably isn't defined. Where is that variable created, and is it created in global scope?

Answer (score 0):

please check below link and change your code.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen

```
<?php

    $current_screen = get_current_screen(); // use this instead of global $current_screen;


?>
```

Comment: if I define the variable like that, it breaks my site.

Comment: Please do var_dump( $current_screen ) and check the result.

Comment: I get a few NULL